# Value from masked text box getting rounded

Tags: vb.net, maskedtextbox

I am trying to set the value of a Single to the converted value of a Masked Text Box.

My Masked Text Box's mask is "00.000000°", meaning it fills in up to 6 decimal points and displays it as degrees.  So say my initial value is `40.12345`, it will show "40.123450°".

This is my line of code to convert it, where `d` is a Single and `msk` is the Masked Text Box:

```
d = CSng(msk.Text.Replace("°", "").Trim)
```

For whatever reason, though, `d`'s value ends up being the contents of the box but rounded to the nearest 5 decimal points!  So say I change it to `40.123457`, the value of `d` ends up being "40.12346".

I do not know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xay7978z.aspx) has low precision. If you want a precise number, I would suggest you use [Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
Dim d As Decimal

d = Decimal.Parse("40.123457°".Replace("°", "").Trim)
```

Comment: OK - it looks like using Decimal.Parse and then putting that into a Double worked.  Strange...I thought a Single should be able to handle 6 decimal points... thank you!

Comment: @Andarta Single can handle 6 decimal in some cases 1.123456 works, 11.123456 doesn't. With double you can still have those problems. Decimal will guarantee that the number will be right.